# Ruby: gem update --system gives this ---> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPRetriableError) 302 "Found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rubygems, redmine

I am trying to install RedMine Project Management tool on Windows. When i Try to run this command "gem update --system", i get the following error:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPRetriableError)
    302 "Found"

I have tried to look for a solution but in vain.

Could anyone suggest a work around for this?

Note: I guess the proxy could be the issue here......

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem. I found an article here that says you need to do a gem update --system which begs the question how you do a gem update --system when that will also give a 302 redirect.

http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/why-do-i-get-http-response-302-or-301-when-installing-a-gem

Not an answer as such but I think it shows that this may not be a firewall issue. If you find out any more info then please let me know.